# Word numbering - Custom Increment of List Item Numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

Word version: Word 2016
OS: Windows 10 Pro

I want to create a list that increments by 10 and not by 1 - i.e.:

-- 10. blah

-- 20. Blah blah

-- 30. blah blah blah

-- 40. You get the idea

Can this be done? prefer not to use the sequence field, definitely don't want to use VBA. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need but I managed to make is by changing `Number Format` under `Define New Number Format` dialog. I just added a `0 (Zero)` between `1` and `.` in `Number format` text box.

[image]

Just in case, this is where you would get `Define New Number Format` option.

[image]